# Update dropdown dynamically while selecting a value - Ionic AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu, ionic-framework

I am building a hyrbid app using Ionic and need the dropdown control to update its value while the user is selecting a value. This way the user does not have to click "Done" or tap elsewhere on the screen to update the dropdown. This will also enable the next control. Ideally the user would select a value, the dropdown would update and unlock the other dropdown.

[image: DropDown Example]

DOM

```
<div class="col">
                <label class="item item-input">
                    <span class="input-label">When</span>
                    <input type="date" id="date" name="date" ng-model="postData.when" required>
                </label>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <label class="item item-input item-select" ng-class="{'disabled' : subForm.date.$pristine}">
                    <div class="input-label">Location</div>
                    <select id="location" name="location" ng-init="postData.location=''" ng-disabled="subForm.date.$pristine" ng-model="postData.location" required>
                        <option value="" disabled hidden></option>
                        <option value="Denver Office">Denver Office</option>
                        <option value="DJ Basin">DJ Basin</option>
                        <option value="East Mediterranean">East Mediterranean</option>
                        <option value="Gulf of Mexico">Gulf of Mexico</option>
                        <option value="Houston Office">Houston Office</option>
                        <option value="Marcellus">Marcellus</option>
                        <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
                        <option value="West Africa">West Africa</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <label class="item item-input item-select" ng-class="{'disabled' : subForm.date.$untouched || subForm.location.$untouched}">
                    <div class="input-label">Observation</div>
                    <select id="observationList" name="observationList" ng-disabled="subForm.date.$untouched || subForm.location.$untouched" ng-model="postData.category" required>
            <option value="" disabled hidden></option>
                        <option value="Caught Between">Caught Between</option>
                        <option value="Dropped Object">Dropped Object</option>
                        <option value="Fall from Height">Fall from Height</option>
                        <option value="Personal Protective Equipment (PPE)">Personal Protective Equipment (PPE)</option>
                        <option value="Slip / Trip / Fall">Slip / Trip / Fall</option>
                        <option value="Strain / Overexertion">Strain / Overexertion</option>
                        <option value="Struck by">Struck by</option>
                        <option value="Spill / Release">Spill / Release</option>
                        <option value="Safe Work Practices">Safe Work Practices</option>
                        <option value="NO HARM">No Harm</option>
                        <option value="Other">Other</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            </div>
            </div>
```

I have tried using the different angular validation check properties such as $untouched, $pristine, etc. But each one waits for the dropdown to lose focus.

Comment: did you manage to solve this issues? I have similar required. I pull the select options via AJAX call only after the user opens the select box. Now because of ASYNC delay, even if the model bind to the select box has the values, select box still is empty. Only if I close the select and reopen I see the new options.

Comment: I was unable to solve the issue. I feel a feature request for Ionic would be appropriate. I ended up leaving each field enabled so the user could select the next one without requiring the input to be valid first.